# Dropdown Not Working with id="<?php echo $post->ID ?>"

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

My drop down menus aren't working, can someone spot the problem and suggest a fix?

```
<div><ul><li><p class="more-info">
<a onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a></ul></li>
<div id="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" class="dropdown-content">
<?php echo $dropdown ?>
</div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("<?php echo $post->ID ?>").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}
</script>
</div>
```

Ive got a live version here - http://www.enjoycompare.com/test-2/

My Style.css

```
.product-box .dropbtn{border:none;cursor:pointer;margin-bottom:5px;}
.product-box .dropdown{position:relative;display:inline-block;}
.product-box .dropdown-content{width:auto;position:relative;margin:0px 20px 0px 20px;}
.product-box .dropdown-content ul{overflow:hidden;margin-left:-18px;margin-bottom:20px;}
.product-box .dropdown-content ul li{width:675px;float:left;margin:0 0 0 18px;padding:2px 0 10px 27px;background:url(img/icons/tick-bullet.png) top left no-repeat;}
.product-box .dropdown-content a {font-family:'Nunito', sans-serif;font-weight:700;padding:10px;color:#222;text-decoration:none;}
.product-box div.dropdown-content:not(.show) { display: none!important; }
```

Comment: Click the `<>` and create a [mcve] without the PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You have plenty of HTML errors in your page](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.enjoycompare.com%2Ftest-2%2F), I guess that at least one (or more) of them effects on your script. Anyway, It should work this way (Your PHP is valid):

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ralolacozi/edit?html,css,js,output) (Note: PHP tags has been removed)

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
   toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $post->ID; ?>").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
div.dropdown-content:not(.show) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p class="more-info">
                <a onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="dropdown-content">
        <?php echo $dropdown; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** In continuation of our discussion at the comments below, You're experiencing the problem because you've placed the script everytime the loop is running, and that's why the script isn't working as expected.

Follow the Instructions below:

1) Move the `script` tag out of the loop, to the bottom of the page (just before the body ending `</body>`)

2) **DO NOT USE PREDEFINED VALUE**: that means, You have the following code:

```
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
   toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("<?php echo $post->ID; ?>").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, You've defined that `<?php echo $post->ID; ?>` will produce the desired element. It could be good, if it was only one element. but you're dealing with multiple elements, and this value override every other possible value.

3) So Instead, do this:

```
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
   toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction(dropdown_id) {
    document.getElementById(dropdown_id).classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

`dropdown_id` will be accessible for you to modify (and re-modify) specifically for each iteration. I mean, all you have to do is simply update your html to:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p class="more-info">
                <a onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $post->ID; ?>')" class="dropbtn">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="dropdown-content">
        <?php echo $dropdown; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just move the PHP from the JavaScript and it will be fixed.

Hope it was helpful and please let me know if something went wrong (and, of course, if it worked as expected).

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I've updated the test page and it doesn't seem to work. Do i need to add something to the my Style.css file?

Comment: You can if you didn't style it yet. Take a look in the demo - I've appended style to the element as long as it doesn't have an `.show` class. *don't forget to press "run with Js" when you're viewing the demo*

Comment: Simply add to your stylesheet `div.dropdown-content:not(.show) { display: none; }` as you can see on the demo - if needed, add `!important` after the "none" (it will force the property to effect the element)

Comment: You can click `<>` and post the runnable code here too

Comment: Ive added the style code to my style.css file and added the !important, but it still doesn't seem to work? its been updated on my test page... can anyone help?

Comment: I think the problem is something to do with my PHP code '<?php echo $post->ID ?>' which I'm using to try and make each post unique, so that the script activates the right dropdown (it works when i remove the PHP, but all links only effect the first dropdown on the page)

Comment: Your php is completely valid and this demonstration too; can you show me in which part (lines) did you inserted this? You can do such thing using phpfiddle or screenshot this part; I'm using mobile right now so it will be harder for me to identify what went wrong on my own

Comment: Ive added my Style.css into the original question - Sorry I'm a total novice and way out of my depth. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to insert space after the "none" (`display: none !important`)

Comment: I took an example of your markup and there's a lot of mess: [Example copied from your source](http://jsbin.com/xagexefodu/edit?html,css,output). as you can see (and also copy this to the validation tool) there are unclosed tags. I suggest you to start fixing these problems because there's a chance that at least one of these errors causing problems while you try to run your script. and also, you can not insert a `div` inside `ul` (unless it's under `li`). Improve your [HTML with MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/html) & [Don't forget to check the markup](https://validator.w3.org).

Comment: Ive checked my code and fixed all the errors and now the dropdown is working, but only on the last product in the list? In fact all the dropdown buttons seems to activate the last product in the list - see on my test page www.enjoycompare.com/test-2

Comment: You've placed the `script` tag in each run of the loop, I'll update my question with a solution. follow the update - it will be soon

Comment: @GregFortune Updated